# How to conditionally handle division by zero with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, this query might throw a division by zero error:

```
SELECT ROUND(noOfBoys / noOfGirls) AS ration
FROM student;
```

If `noOfGirls` is `0` then the calculation fails.

What is the best way to handle this?

I would like to conditionally change the value of `noOfGirls` to `1` when it is equal to `0`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: MySQL does not throw division by zero errors.

Comment: @UncleIroh It depends on the MySQL configuration. If the MySQL server has `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` mode enabled, it will issue an error when a division by zero occurred.

Comment: @Metafaniel Interesting I did not know that.  Thanks.

Comment: need to use  if else statment in mysql

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can do a case:

```
select case when noOfGirls=0 then noOfBoys 
       else  round(noOfBoys/noOfGirls) end as ration 
from student;
```

But you probably want:

```
select case when noOfGirls=0 then 1 
       else  round(noOfBoys/noOfGirls) end as ration 
from student;
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this (over-expressive) way:

```
select IF(noOfGirls=0, NULL, round(noOfBoys/noOfGirls)) as ration from student;
```

Which will put out NULL if there are no girls, which is effectively what 0/0 should be in SQL semantics.

MySQL will anyway give `NULL` if you try to do `0/0`, as the SQL meaning fo `NULL` is "no data", or in this case "I don't know what this value can be".

Answer (score 5):

**`GREATEST(x, 1)`**

Can be used since the number of girls must be positive:

```
SELECT ROUND(noOfBoys / GREATEST(noOfGirls, 1)) AS ration FROM student;
```

But it is not very portable across SQL implementations.

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to set noOfGirls to 1 if it's 0, then the following should work:

```
SELECT ROUND(noOfBoys / if(noOfGirls, noOfGirls, 1)) as ration FROM student;
```

Answer (score 2):

Division by `NULL` actually works in MySQL server and returns `NULL`. So you can do:

```
SELECT ROUND(noOfBoys / NULLIF(noOfGirls, 0)) AS ration FROM student;
```

I think `NULL` ratio is the most accurate for this case. If you need the ratio to be equal to `numOfBoys` then you can use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(noOfBoys / NULLIF(noOfGirls, 0)), noOfBoys) AS ration FROM student;
```

Comment: It depends on `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` mode. If it's enabled then MySQL will fail with error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    case student.noOfGirls
           when 0 then 1
           else  round(noOfBoys/noOfGirls)
    end as ration
from
    `student`
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the denominator is zero and the nominator is not NULL - if yes then use 'NaN'.