# MySQL: How to avoid division by zero when ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql, divide-by-zero

I need to do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Video WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY votesUp/votesDown DESC
```

But I'm aware that `votesDown` can bear 0 (zero) as its value. How can I workaround to avoid the division by zero?

**OBS**: In my case, it's okay to make `votesDown` turn to 1, when 0.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Video WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY votesUp/IF(votesDown = 0, 1, votesDown) DESC ??

Comment: @InoS Heo Yes! It works. Sorry if it was so obvious, I'm just new to MySQL. Post as answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: Personally I would just use `(votesUp+1/votesDown+1)`. The ordering would be much the same, though I can't prove that mathematically right now.

Comment: @Kylotan I see your point. It's very clever, once it kills the problem and the constant is irrelevant as the numbers get larger. Awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to conditionally handle division by zero with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245438/how-to-conditionally-handle-division-by-zero-with-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `IF()` function, you can convert `0` to `1`.
Could you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Video
WHERE visible = 1 
ORDER BY votesUp / IF(votesDown = 0, 1, votesDown) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
SELECT * FROM Video WHERE visible = 1
ORDER BY votesUp / CASE votesDown WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE votesDown END DESC;
```

However, you would usually order by the percentage of upvotes of all votes. When there are no votes at all, the result is undefined, so use NULL then:

```
SELECT * FROM Video WHERE visible = 1
ORDER BY votesUp / NULLIF(votesUp + votesDown, 0) DESC;
```