# How to overcome divide by zero error in following query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please find an table structure below

```
table A      Table B
10              10
20              10
30              0
40              0
```

I want to divide A/B.
if there is 30/0 i wan to display it as 0.

I want to output like

```
O/P
1
2
0
0
```

How Can we do that?

```
Table structure queries:
create table #test1(id int)

insert into #test1 values(10)
insert into #test1 values(20)
insert into #test1 values(30)
insert into #test1 values(40)

select top 100 * from #test1

create table #test2(id int)

insert into #test2 values(10)
insert into #test2 values(10)
insert into #test2 values(0)
insert into #test2 values(0)

select top 100 * from #test2
```

Comment: Mysql or (MS) SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally handle division by zero with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245438/how-to-conditionally-handle-division-by-zero-with-mysql)

Comment: Seeing this is two tables, what makes you decide for the four pairings? Why divide 10 by 10 for instance and not 10 by 0? You seem to have some order in mind, but tables have no inherent order. Do you want to order A ascending and B descending and then build pairs top down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select A, B, case B when 0 then B else A/B end [A/B]
from (values (10,10),(20,10),(30,0),(40,0)) tbl(A,B)
```

Above query uses `case` statement to return `0` when `B = 0` and divide when `B <> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A.id,B.id, IIF(B.id<>0,A.Id/B.ID,0) AS ExpectedResult,
       COALESCE( A.id/NULLIF(B.ID,0),0)  AS ExpectedResult2
FROM
(
SELECT Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order BY ID) As Seq FROM #test1
)As A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order BY ID DESC) As Seq FROM #test2)AS B
ON A.Seq=B.Seq
```

Result

```
 id id  ExpectedResult  ExpectedResult2
10  10     1                    1
20  10     2                    2
30  0      0                    0
40  0      0                    0
```

Comment: It's Working...Thanks