# MySQL - division by zero

Tags: mysql

When I run this query:

```
UPDATE pics SET voteup = voteup - 1, score = ROUND((voteup * 100) / (voteup + votedown))
```

then I get the error

> division by zero

when `voteup` and `votedown` are `0`

I've seen

[How to conditionally handle division by zero with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245438/how-to-conditionally-handle-division-by-zero-with-mysql)

but I don't know how to use it for my specific case

Comment: Does this work?
UPDATE pics SET voteup = voteup - 1, score = ROUND((voteup * 100) / NULLIF(voteup + votedown, 0))

Comment: @N.Kern this way I get the error: Column 'score' cannot be null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally handle division by zero with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245438/how-to-conditionally-handle-division-by-zero-with-mysql)

Comment: ...if this really does not help, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase is alerady solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both voteup + votedown is 0 then 0 else expected logic for ignoring divide by zero error.

```
-- MySQL
UPDATE pics 
SET voteup = voteup - 1
  , score = CASE WHEN (voteup + votedown) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND((voteup * 100) / (voteup + votedown)) END
```